# How to choose good pass and stop band frequency for my low pass filter?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, ipc, communication, lowpass-filter

I have a noisy signal length of 512 points with sampling frequency 5 Hz. And my task is the pull out 0.2 Hz component form  main signal using LPF. How can i choose good pass and stop band frequencies? Is there any rule or requirements related to the input data for choosing that parameters?

Comment: For a low pass filter you only have a cutoff frequency, not pass band and stop band frequencies. Try a cutoff frequency a little higher than 0.2 Hz to keep the 0.2-Hz component and reject higher frequencies

Comment: @LuisMendo it depends on the filter design technique you are using, there are designs, which let you choose pass and stop band frequencies for low pass filter, see [Controlling Design Specifications in Lowpass FIR Design](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/controlling-filter-variables-in-lowpass-fir-deign.html)

Comment: @Irreducible Good point. But in that case there is usually an "attenuation mask", given as input, which specifies acceptable attenuation ranges on those bands. That doesn't seem to be the case in this question

Comment: @LuisMendo I guess the OP is not aware of having this degree of freedom. Nevertheless I agree that choosing a cutoff  a little higher is a good choise, as the transition width will be small in this way (twice as big as a little higher ;) )